# Can't compile scala/SBT project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

When I try to run ( through SBT) my scala program I run into a bunch of errors.

Here's an excerpt:

```
[error] missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'IterableUtils.class'.
[error] Could not access type ScalaObject in package scala,
[error] because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
[error] missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'IterableUtils.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of scala.
[error] missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'AsBooleanTrait.class'.
[error] Could not access type ScalaObject in package scala,
[error] because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
[error] missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)

.....
```

I did add the scala-library.jar to the classpath but to no avail.  Does anyone know what might be missing?

Ps. used -> new SBT project (Intellij) on osx

edit: here's the build.sbt

```
name := "test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

resolvers += "Scales XML" at "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalesxml/scales-xml_2.9.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalesxml" % "scales-xml_2.9.1" % "0.3-RC7"
```

SBT is version 0.13.8

**Edit 2:**

Figured it out. I was trying to run a class (with a main method) without creating an instance... After changing it to an Object things work a lot better :)

**Edit 3:**

Spoke too soon. I turns out it has to do with setting the scalaVersion in build.sbt.  When I leave that entire line out, it no longer complains about the missing dependencies. When I put it back in I get the errors mentioned above back. I tried setting it to 2.11.7 as well ( after installing that with brew install scala) but to no avail.

Comment: Could you edit your post and add your `build.sbt` file ?

Comment: What versions of SDK, SBT and Scala did you choose?

Comment: Updated as requested

Comment: What command do you use to run your project ?

Comment: 'sbt run'  in terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
>
> libraryDependencies += "org.scalesxml" % "scales-xml_2.9.1" % "0.3-RC7"
> ```

You can't use a library compiled for Scala 2.9.1 with Scala 2.11.*. Write `"org.scalesxml" %% "scales-xml" %` some-version instead, which will look for `scales-xml_2.11`. See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Cross-Build.html.